# Send traffic info to another Google Analytics account

Tags: google-analytics, cross-domain, user-tracking

We have traffic being driven to our site by an affiliate.  They send traffic to a private label we made (a new skin on our site).

We track our users via GA.  They would like access to the data for users on their private label.

Is there a way that we can automatically provide this to them?  Preferably so that it shows up with their existing tracking data?

Answer (score 1):

You could just add the other account information. I have done this successfully in the past. You just have to set up your markers correctly.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
var _gaq = _gaq || [];

_gaq.push(['UA_123456_1._setAccount', 'UA-123456-1']);
_gaq.push(['UA_123456_1._setDomainName', '.example.com']);
_gaq.push(['UA_123456_2._setAccount', 'UA-123456-2']);
_gaq.push(['UA_123456_2._setDomainName', '.example.com']);

_gaq.push(['UA_123456_1._trackPageview']);
_gaq.push(['UA_123456_2._trackPageview']);

</script>
```

Comment: How can I do this without giving them data for all of our visitors?

Comment: I am not sure. I may have misunderstood the initial question. Is the 'them' in your follow-on question referring to the affiliate or Google?

Comment: @Johathan: Our affiliate - they have a private label, which is a reskinning of a page without changing the content.

Comment: If you use something similar to the snippet I provided on the pages for your affiliate, then the tracking data for those page views would be sent to each tracker, but only for those page views. In the past, when I have implemented something like this, I used as server side process to determine which trackers should be included in the output. You could conceivably include it as a part of whatever mechanism you are using to determine which skin to show.